# Rails "has_one" relation. Assign Project to Customer(Timestamp)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, table-relationships

I'm building a time tracker. You can create a timestamp with a start time, end time, customer and a project from this customer. So you can see how much time you've spent for a project or customer.

The relationships between tables with "has_many" works perfectly but I have a problem with the "has_one" relation.

**My tables:**

```
timestamps              customers             projects
----------              ------------          -----------
id:integer              id:integer            id:integer
desc:string             customer_name:string  project_name:string
customer_id:interger    project_id:integer
```

**My models:**

timestamp.rb

```
class Timestamp < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :customer
    has_one :project, through: :customer
end
```

customer.rb

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :timestamp
   has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
end
```

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer  
end
```

**My goals:**

1. Create one timestamp with associated customer and project: `Timestamp.create({desc: "Something", customer_id: "1", project_id: "6"})`
2. Get project from timestamp: `Timestamp.find(1).customer.project`

**My problem:**

I can make this work if I include a timestamp_id into the projects table but with this method, Rails duplicates every project with the specific timestamp_id when I'm creating a new timestamp. But I want to assign one project_id to the timestamp.

FYI: I'm using rails 4.2.6 with a MYSQL Database.

Comment: shouldn't it be `has_many :projects, through: :customer` in your timestamp.rb? because one customer has_many projects. If you intentionally use has_one, then it will only fetch the first project from the list

Comment: Your are right. But this doesn't solve the problem. But thank you!

Comment: What is `Timestamp` in your app, what is it's purpose and how does it differ from Active Record timestamps? I ask because this smells like an XY problem and you're stuck turning a dysfunctional solution into functional code. Perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: @sebastian Do you want to implement many to many relation like project has many customers and customer has many projects ? If not then use simple relations without through convention.

Comment: @Substantial I'm building a time tracker. You can create a timestamp with a start time, end time, customer and a project from this customer. So you can see how much time did you spend for one project or customer.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli I want a timestamp which has a customer list, start time and end time. If i select a customer the projects from this customer pops up and you can select these. So if you save the timestamp you have a start and end time as well the associated  customer with the project. So you can see how long you have been working for a specific customer or project.

Comment: You mean timestamp is for project start and end time but no direct relation with customer right ?

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli Right. start_time and end_time are columns in the timestamps table. Projects don't have start or end times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do not want to have duplicate projects and duplicate customers per timestamp, then you'd need to set only foreign keys to the timestamp. By that you would want to have tables with the following columns:

```
Timestamps
  customer_id:integer:index
  project_id:integer:index

Customers

Projects
  customer_id:integer:index
```

You'll have to write and run migrations to remove columns, and add columns so that it will look above.

Then, modify associations:

```
class Timestamp < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer # change to belongs_to
  has_many :projects, through: :customer # you might not need this anymore because of the line below
  belongs_to :project # add this line
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :timestamp # change to has_one
   has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_one :timestamp # add this line
end
```

Then, you could now use the following

```
Timestamp.find(1).customer
Timestamp.find(1).project
Timestamp.find(1).projects # these projects are customer.projects and are not directly associated to the line above, so I don't think you would need to call this
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks everybody! @Jay-Ar Polisario your answer didn't work perfectly but it got me thinking about my "has_one / has_many" relations and because of this it worked after hours of rethinking these. Thank you.

**For everybody, who came here from Google to find an answer to a similar problem:**

Go ahead an start drawing your tables and columns on a board or paper. Make the relationships visual! This helped me figuring out the right relations.